# getting second parameter null in post in mvc and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using httppost action in controller and calling using angular js. but getiing second parameter always null.

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Services_PageSize(string PageSize, string ServiceCategory_Id)
        {
            int n;
            bool isNumericPageSize = int.TryParse(PageSize, out n);
            bool isNumericServiceCategory_Id = int.TryParse(ServiceCategory_Id, out n);
        return new JsonResult { Data = new { Services = _Services, Status =        isNumericPageSize }, };
        }
```

and my angular js controller is

```
 this.getServices = function (pageSize, ServiceCategoryId) {
           return $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "/Home/Services_PageSize?pageSize=" + pageSize + "& ServiceCategoryId=" + ServiceCategoryId

        });
```

Comment: Where are you actually setting the value for ServiceCategoryId? Can you put debugger and see whether the value actually being passed to angular controller for ServiceCategoryId?

Comment: both parameter has value. url created by code is /Home/Services_PageSize?pageSize=4& ServiceCategoryId=1.

Comment: Sir it calls action method but value of second parameter is null

Comment: @user3374631 could you look at mine answer

Answer (score 0):

You second parameter should be `ServiceCategory_Id` instead of `ServiceCategoryId` (`_` has been missed from paramter name).

```
this.getServices = function (pageSize, ServiceCategoryId) {
     return $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/Home/Services_PageSize?pageSize=" + pageSize + "& ServiceCategory_Id=" + ServiceCategoryId
    });
}
```

Better option would be post call data should be pass from the data option of `post`

```
this.getServices = function (pageSize, ServiceCategoryId) {
     return $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/Home/Services_PageSize",
        data: {
           PageSize: pageSize,
           ServiceCategory_Id: ServiceCategoryId
        }
    });
}
```